# How to select element using boolean matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, indexing

I'm trying to select some elements by using boolean operations in MATLAB.

I have `A = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9]`

```
A =

 1     2     3
 4     5     6
 7     8     9
```

When using `A([true true false; true true false])` I get:

```
 1
 4
 7
 2
```

Isn't it supposed to be?:

```
 1
 4
 2
 5
```

Does anyone know what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

See [this example](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#bq7egb6-1) for the documentation on [logical indexing](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#bq7egb6-1). It may not be explained as clearly as it should, but if you specify a logical index with fewer elements that then the indexed matrix (`A`) then the indexing matrix is linearized such that:

```
A = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9];
idx1 = [true true false; true true false];
A(idx1)
```

is equivalent to:

```
idx1 = [true true false; true true false];
A(idx1(:))
```

In other words, the index matrix (`idx1`) elements specify the output in column-wise order.

If you want what you though you should get, you can use:

```
idx2 = [true false true; true true false];
A(idx2)
```

or you can transform your original index array:

```
idx1 = [true true false; true true false];
idx2 = reshape(idx1.',2,3);
A(idx2)
```

or just use:

```
idx3 = [true true false true true].';
A(idx3)
```